# How to set jmeter script for calling API1 first and then API2 in sequencial

Tags: automation, jmeter

I have a test plan i need to run the following API in sequential order:

> - add record to DB using API POST call for user role to add to db
> - Update record using API PUT call to update user role
> - delete record using API DELETE call.This should be DELETE that record from DB using API call

This is the flow i need to achieve for each run.

Comment: Try this [LINK](https://octoperf.com/blog/2018/04/23/jmeter-rest-api-testing/)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything special, JMeter executed [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) sequentially (from top to bottom) so just add 3 [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers in the order you need

[image]

And JMeter will execute the requests in the given order:

[image]

Most probably you will also need to add a [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager/) to send the relevant [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header for your API.